# Does 09:00-05:00 mean the same thing as 9:00 AM EST?

Tags: datetime, timezone

I converted time from `01:00 PM GMT` to EST and I got `09:00-05:00`

My question is can I just say `9 AM EST`, without the `-05:00`? Does it basically mean the same thing after the daylight saving starts?

The reason I want to know is because I do not want the trailing `-5:00`, and `9 AM` is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

> I converted time from `01:00 PM GMT` to EST and I got `09:00-05:00`

You did something wrong in your conversion then.  `-05:00` means the time given is 5 hours behind UTC.  Since `1:00 PM` is the 12-hour-clock representation of `13:00`, and `13 - 5 = 8`, then the equivalent time that is 5 hours behind would be `08:00`, not `09:00`.

> My question is can I just say `9 AM EST`, without the `-05:00`? Does it basically mean the same thing after the daylight saving starts?

No, they do not mean the same thing.

- `EST` is an English time zone abbreviation which typically means "Eastern Standard Time", such as applies in both North and South America, including some places that use daylight saving time, and some places that don't.  `EST` only refers to the period where DST is not in effect, and says nothing about whether it will be later or not.
- `-05:00` is a fixed offset from UTC, which applies to multiple other time zones than just `EST`.  For example, it can also apply to US Central Daylight Time (CDT), as well as Peru's `PET` or the daylight time that applies on Chile's Easter Island (with a very different DST period).

Even if you meant "US Eastern Time", you would use the abbreviation `EDT` for the period during daylight saving time, and it caries an offset of `-04:00`.

If in your original conversion you meant EDT, then the result would be `09:00-04:00`.

> The reason I want to know is because I do not want the trailing `-5:00`, and `9 AM` is more readable.

That's a valid concern.  When it comes to how you *display* data, you can certainly omit information that may not be relevant to your users.  Assuming your users only care about the local hour in US Eastern Time, then displaying `9 AM` is fine.

Just don't make the mistake of doing this in *data*, such as JSON, XML, or in a file.  Otherwise, the computer interpreting your data may end up applying a different time zone.

Of course, this part is entirely up to you, and will vary by use case.